# Can't access Kafka from a Java app. What may be the problem?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I managed to successfully set up Zookeeper and Kafka servers, and CLI pub/sub operations work fine

```
jorejoh@LAPTOP-CKP86E2O:/usr/local/kafka/bin$ ./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test                                                                                                SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.                                                                                                                                                               SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/kafka/tools/build/dependant-libs-2.13.10/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/kafka/trogdor/build/dependant-libs-2.13.10/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]                                                        
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/kafka/connect/runtime/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]                                                        
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/kafka/connect/mirror/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]                                                         
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.                                                                                                                                   
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Reload4jLoggerFactory]                                                                                                                                            
>Another message                                                                                                                                                                                                   
>Yet another message                                                                                                                                                                                               
>^C
jorejoh@LAPTOP-CKP86E2O:/usr/local/kafka/bin$  ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning                                                                         
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.                                                                                                                                                                
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/kafka/tools/build/dependant-libs-2.13.10/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]                                                          
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/kafka/trogdor/build/dependant-libs-2.13.10/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]                                                        
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/kafka/connect/runtime/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]                                                        
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/kafka/connect/mirror/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]                                                         
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.                                                                                                                                   
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Reload4jLoggerFactory]                                                                                                                                            
Another message                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Yet another message                                                                                                                                                                                                
^CProcessed a total of 2 messages
```

However, when I try to perform similar operations from a simple Java app, it can't connect. Here's the app code:

```java
package org.example.demos.kafka;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

import java.util.Properties;

public class ProducerMicroservice {

    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "my-topic";
    private static final String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "localhost:9092";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Configure Kafka producer
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

        // Generate and send messages
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            String message = "Message " + i;
            ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC_NAME, message);
            producer.send(record);
        }

        // Close the producer
        producer.close();
    }
}
```

```java
package org.example.demos.kafka;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ConsumerMicroservice {

    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "my-topic";
    private static final String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "localhost:9092";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Configure Kafka consumer
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("group.id", "my-group");
        try (Consumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props)) {
            // Subscribe to the topic and start consuming messages
            consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(TOPIC_NAME));
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
                records.forEach(record -> {
                    System.out.println("Received message: " + record.value());
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A snippet from a producer log:

```
---- 07 сент. 2023 18:39:51,168
DEBUG [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] : Resolved host localhost as 127.0.0.1

---- 07 сент. 2023 18:39:51,168
DEBUG [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating connection to node localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) using address localhost/127.0.0.1

---- 07 сент. 2023 18:39:51,169
DEBUG [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 (channelId=-1) disconnected

 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:50) ~[kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:224) ~[kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:526) [kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481) [kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:571) [kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.isReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:42) [kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:64) [kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.awaitNodeReady(Sender.java:534) [kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.maybeSendAndPollTransactionalRequest(Sender.java:455) [kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:316) [kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:243) [kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
---- 07 сент. 2023 18:39:51,169
INFO  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.

---- 07 сент. 2023 18:39:51,170
WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

---- 07 сент. 2023 18:39:51,170
WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

---- 07 сент. 2023 18:39:51,170
DEBUG [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Disconnect from localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) while trying to send request InitProducerIdRequestData(transactionalId=null, transactionTimeoutMs=2147483647, producerId=-1, producerEpoch=-1). Going to back off and retry.

 java.io.IOException: Connection to localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) failed.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:70) ~[kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.awaitNodeReady(Sender.java:534) ~[kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.maybeSendAndPollTransactionalRequest(Sender.java:455) [kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:316) [kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:243) [kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
```

I made sure that:

1. Kafka versions are compatible (both are 3.5.1)
2. I specified this property in the `server.properties` file (notice `advertised.listeners` is still commented out so it should take regular listeners):

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: The service is running on *the same box as on which the code is being run*?

Comment: @g00se I'm not sure what you mean, but I have only one computer so it's all run on the same machine (the services and the Kafka server)

Comment: In that case, the concern I had is not relevant

Comment: When you start the process, sometimes they get binded to listen on 127.0.0.1 vs localhost etc., can you check the PID for Kafka server process and see is it open to listen on "localhost" too?

Comment: @kosa the PID is 1748. What should I take from it?

Comment: My guess is that this has to do with WSL, which is tagged but not otherwise mentioned in the question. I don’t know anything about WSL personally, but I can see that the tag has many similar questions about networking between the subsystem and the host. I didn’t see one with an answer, however.

Comment: @TimMoore I think your observation is very valid.